# when I insert a value into a <li>,that I created using jQuery, the value appears in another line not next to the point, and it doesn't look good

Tags: jquery

when I insert a value into a li the value appears in another line not next to the point, in it's look good.
but when I make list-style:none only then the good looks cool, I want my list to be displayed with the point but in the same like as normal

```js
$("#screen1").click(function(){
  var value = prompt("writesomething", "here");
  
  $("ul").append("<li>",value,"</li>");
  $("li").addClass("myclass");
  
  
});
```

```css
#screen1 {
    background: #43b29d;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
}
#myUl li{
  margin:10px;
}

.myclass{
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="screen1">

  <ul id="myUl">
    
  </ul>
  
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried parsing the script output?
[image]
As you can see the text is inserted outside the HTML tags.

So to solve it, just replace the:

```
$("ul").append("<li>",value,"</li>");
```

with:

```
$("ul").append($("<li/>").text(value));
```

By doing so you create a new jQuery element (LI tag), insert the desired text into it, avoiding any malicious HTML ignition and add everything to the UL tag.

I hope to be proved helpful.. :)

Comment: thank you very much guys, I really appreciate. it's working well now, I had to Concatinate using the "+" not the comma  ","

Comment: Yes, but for security reasons it is always recommended to use the TEXT function to avoid problems. for example if you enter **<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>** it will be executed creating a real flap in the page security.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Removed dangerous string concatination

Concatinate using .text like Pinguto proposed

```js
$("#screen1").click(function(){
  var value = prompt("writesomething", "here");
  $("ul").append($("<li/>").text(value));
  $("li").addClass("myclass");
  
  
});
```

```css
#screen1 {
    background: #43b29d;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
}
#myUl li{
  margin:10px;
}

.myclass{
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="screen1">

  <ul id="myUl">
    
  </ul>
  
    </section>
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend, I really appreciate it. it's working well now, I had to concatenate using the "+" not the comma ",".  thank you again for correcting my mistake